# SQL Express 2017 Service Broker, stored procedure not activated from queue

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm trying to use service broker on a SQL Server 2017 Express edition. I followed the steps at [Asynchronous procedure execution](http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/).

Simply created an empty DB and cut & paste all the steps from Rusanu's blog, but the SP associated to the queue doesn't run. I see entry in the companion table, but queue is always empty and SP doesn't run. Executing SP manually, produce no errors.

That blog post is quite old, maybe it's no longer valid for SQL Server 2017 ? Or maybe there are limitations on Express edition? Anyway I never got an error, even when I attached the SP to the queue. If there were limitations I expected an error. Looking at queue properties, SP name is there.

Comment: Have you run ssbdiagnose on your setup to see if it had anything to say?

Comment: What @BenThul said, I'd also use SQL Profiler to inspect any kind of activity in your SQL Instance, you might see some errors that would indicate your issue.

Comment: Express edition has no SQL profiler and also ssbdiagnose seems missing.